# Spring not wire beans

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I starting learning spring and wanted to try an example. I wrote the 3 classes bellow bat it seems that I am missing something because the String does not do what i intended to do.

```
package testPackage;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

@ContextConfiguration(classes=Config.class)
public class TestDrive {

    @Autowired
    private InterfaceClass obj;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestDrive testDrive = new TestDrive();

        System.out.println(testDrive.obj);
        }
}
```

```
package testPackage;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

public class TestClass implements InterfaceClass {

    public String test = "test string";

    @Bean
    public TestClass getTestClass() {

        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();

        return testClass;
    }

}
```

```
package testPackage;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Config {

}
```

When I run this code from main I get "null" printed.
Why Spring does not wire "InterfaceClass obj"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Declare your ***Spring Beans*** in the class marked *@Configuration*

2) In *main* function, use ApplicationContext to get TestDrive object. **Never mix Spring bean objects with objects created from new operator**

TestDrive Class

```
public class TestDrive {

    @Autowired
    private InterfaceClass obj;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //you will have to use this method, to get bean of TestDrive
        // You should not use new operator, not advisable to mix new operator with spring beans
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        TestDrive drive = context.getBean(TestDrive.class);

        System.out.println(drive.getString());

    }

    public String getString(){
        String str = obj.getTestString();
        return str;
    }
}
```

TestClass

```
public class TestClass implements InterfaceClass{
    public String test = "test string";
    public String getTestString(){
        return test;
    }
```

}

InterfaceClass

```
public interface InterfaceClass {
    public String getTestString();
}
```

Config

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public InterfaceClass getTestClass() {
        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
        return testClass;
    }

    @Bean
    public TestDrive getTestDrive(){
        return  new TestDrive();
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: `@Configuration` is meta-annotated with `@Component`. Any annotation which is meta-annotated with `@Component` would work including `@Component`.

Comment: I've added the method to Config class but i still get "null'.

Comment: Yes, I moved the method getTestClass() from TestClass to Confing.

Comment: Thank you very much! They key was the **"new" operator**. I should rely only on spring beans!

Answer (score 1):

put `@Configuration` annotation on top of test class :-

```
package testPackage;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

@Configuration
public class TestClass implements InterfaceClass {

    public String test = "test string";

    @Bean
    public TestClass getTestClass() {

        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();

        return testClass;
    }

}
```

Comment: I've added @Configuration  but I still get "null".